# ECSlidingViewController loading from XIB

Tags: ios, loading, xib

I want to use this [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) in my project. Example app from link uses storyboards, but i want to load all from xibs.
What i must implement in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: to do this?

Code from example app:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = (ECSlidingViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
  UIStoryboard *storyboard;

  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];
  } else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle:nil];
  }

  slidingViewController.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstTop"];

  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using storyboards to get an instance of the UIViewController, you can instantiate it from a nib:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = [[ECSlidingViewController alloc] init];

  FirstTopViewController *firstTop = [[FirstTopViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstTop" bundle:nil];
  slidingViewController.topViewController = firstTop;

  self.window.rootViewController = slidingViewController

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: That's not true if you try above code you will get "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" error from Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Try this that worked on my env.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.initialViewController = [[InitialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InitialViewController" bundle:nil];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.initialViewController;

  ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = (ECSlidingViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;   
  FirstViewController *firstController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
  slidingViewController.topViewController = firstController;

  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;    
}
```

and also do not forget to add

```
    [self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:280.0f];
```

into your firstviewcontroller's viewWillAppear method.

Good luck

Comment: Doesn't work. It says *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'